# I don't get what I want with substr

Tags: c++, substr

I want to get all the sub string possible, there is the following code for it (with all library included), which n is the length of the string s :

```
long substrCount(int n, string s) {
    string sub;
    vector<string> s2;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j <= n-i; j++){
            sub = s.substr(i,j);
            if(sub != "")
                s2.push_back(sub);
        }
}
```

But when I tried with the main for the string "asasd", I get

```
> s2
> ={a,as,asa,asas,asasd,a,as,asa,asas,asasd,s,sa,sas,sasd,a,as,asa,asas,asasd,s,sa,sas,sasd,a,as,asd,a,as,asa,asas,asasd,s,sa,sas,sasd,a,as,asd,s,sd,a,as,asa,asas,asasd,s,sa,sas,sasd,a,as,asd,s,sd,d}
```

I do not understand why, the index i is from 0 to n. I should have the string beginning by 's' just after the first asasd.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it doesn't compile: you are missing a end-brace `}` and return statement. You also don't include how you are printing/examining the vector. I bring this up because (after addressing those concerns) [your code works just fine](https://ideone.com/bIbq23). So perhaps the issue lies in something you haven't provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide enough detail in your question. I can provide you with an alternative. For this example I don't use a `vector`

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void subString(std::string, int);


int main()
{
    std::string s2 = "asad";
    subString(s2, s2.length());
    return 0;
}

void subString(std::string s, int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
            std::cout << s.substr(i, j) << std::endl;
    }
        
           
}
```

Output:

```
a
as
asa
asad
s
sa
sad
a
ad
d
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand what is different with my code, you just changed j from 0 to n-i by j from 1 to n-i, It should not change anything, because I put an if statement which remove the empty string

Comment: You should not tell OP to not use a vector... that wasn't the problem with his code. Who knows, he might need the vector for later.

Comment: @RyanJonZhang, I didn't tell him to *not* use a vector. I told him he doesn't *need* a `vector` for this specific example. You can do this problem multifarious ways. That's all.

Comment: And yes, I need the vector for the next

Answer (score 0):

Because first you fix i to 0 and you iterate over the entire j-based loop, then you increment i to 1and re-do the j based loop, and so on...
You can check this easily with a debugger.

Comment: If I increment i from 0 to 1, I should get world which begin by s for "asasd", not again word which begin by a, no ?

Comment: Nope. First you get i,j=0,0 i,j=0,1 i,j=0,2... And so on